# AWS glue csv table - adding new columns only in new files query data is broken

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a csv table declared in Glue (created with a crawler from files in S3)
I want to add new columns only in the new files processed (old files in the table still have old scheme).
I've tried adding the new files and running the crawler again but the result for the queries (done with athena) returns with the data not in the correct column.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What I finally did was to make sure the new columns will be added at the end of the table (last cols) and this way I was able to create a new scheme for the table without the destruction of existing columns.